# How can I get JupyterLite to work again as it has stopped working entirely?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I have been using the browser version on JupyterLite for a few weeks. As of a few days ago, anything I type into a row does nothing when I select Run. Even entering a basic print() doesn't do anything. Can anyone help me? thanks.

I have tried opening up a new tab, entering many different things, and nothing seems to work?

[image: 1]

Comment: Which JupyterLite source are you using? You can try in a new browser? Often I'll use the same browser and try the incognito mode to get what resembles a clean version. You have to be patient with that though and let it load everything and have the kernel indicator go to ready before trying stuff. Plus make sure you start and dismiss and then 'skip' the tour. I think one running a slightly older version is [here](https://jmshea.github.io/digicom-jupyter). Maybe trying that will work. With each new one you have to be patient before trying. Wait for the kernel indicator go to ready & then start.

Comment: Also, you can go [here](https://github.com/jtpio/jupyterlite) and press the `launch binder` badge and that will open the current JupyterLite backed by a connection to a temporary remote machine. Be careful to save anything useful you make right back to your local machine as it is temporary machine the connection is to. It can be useful when something is weird on your machine and you want to try a different source of things to compare. Point is that sometimes just a different address helps, but be careful **because via that way won't be persistent**.

Comment: Hi Wayne. Thanks for your help, I appreciate it. The kernel is set to busy so I think this is why it wasn't working for me. I tried the link to the older version and that worked. I have now downloaded the desktop version [here](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab-desktop/releases) and it works fine so far.

Comment: Glad you made some progress. I thought you preferred to work with JupyterLite though. Had I realized you wanted to work with JupyterLab like in the JupyterLab Desktop app, I'd also have recommended MyBinder more. The normal launches via that service have a full Python backed kernel. I like it because it keeps my environments organized and portable. And also I'm not installing many environments on the many computers I use that way. Of course it needs the internet to work.